# Error in backend of REST API: "INFO: The connection was broken. It was probably closed by the client. Reason: Closed"

Tags: java, json, rest, jetty, restlet-2.3.1

So I am trying out a simple full stack project of my own that involves a java backend implementation of a REST API, for which I am using the `org.restlet.com` framework/package and jetty as the server.

Whilst I was testing my API using Postman I noticed something wierd: Every time I started the server only the first `POST/PUT/DELETE HTTP` Request would get an answer, while the next ones would not receive one and on the console this error message would appear:

> /* Timestamp-not-important */ org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter commit
>
> INFO: The connection was broken. It was probably closed by the client.
>   Reason: Closed

The GET HTTP Requests however do not share that problem.

I said "Fair enough, probably it's postman's fault".. after all the request made it to the server and their effects were applied. However, now that I am building the front-end this problem blocks the server's response: instead of a `JSON` object I get an `undefined` (edit: actually I get `204 No Content`) on the front-end and the same "INFO" on the back-end for every `POST/PUT/DELETE` after the first one.

I have no idea what it is or what I am doing wrong. It has to be the backend's problem, right? But what should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it was the stupidest thing ever. I tried to be "smart" about returning the same Representation object (with only a 'success' JSON field) on multiple occasions by making one instance on a static final field of a class. Turns out a new instance must be returned each time.